# How to display health for character in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am attempting to draw a health bar for a character in pygame. I am getting an error saying name 'draw_shield_bar' is not defined. I have tried player.draw_shield_bar and still doesn't work. Can someone help with the notation. Below I have included the code which calls the function and then the player class which defines that function. Help would be appreciated.

```
   def draw(self):
        # Game Loop - draw

        whitehouse = pg.image.load("whiteHouseBG.png")
        self.screen.blit(whitehouse,(0,0))

        self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)
        self.draw_text(str(self.score), 22, WHITE, WIDTH / 2, 15)


        draw_shield_bar(self.screen, 50, 50, player.shield)
        # *after* drawing everything, flip the display
        pg.display.flip()

class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.game = game
        self.walking = False
        self.jumping = False
        self.current_frame = 0
        self.last_update = 0
        self.load_images()
#me:girl standing
        self.image = self.girl_standing[0]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT/2)
        self.pos = vec(WIDTH/2, HEIGHT*3/4)
        self.vel = vec(0, 0)
        self.acc = vec(0, 0)
        self.shield = 100
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()

    def draw_shield_bar(surf, x, y, pct):
        if pct < 0:
            pct = 0
        BAR_LENGTH = 200
        BAR_HEIGHT = 20
        fill = (pct/100 * BAR_LENGTH)
        outline_rect = pg.Rect(x, y, BAR_LENGTH, BAR_HEIGHT)
        fill_rect = pg.Rect(x, y, fill, BAR_HEIGHT)
        pg.draw.rect(surf, GREEN, fill_rect)
        pg.draw.rect(surf, WHITE, outline_rect, 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `player` is an instance of the `Player` class, using `player.draw_shield_bar`is correct. The reason it fails, is probably because you forgot to use `self` as the first argument of the draw_shield_bar method. It should be:

```
def draw_shield_bar(self, surf, x, y, pct):
```

If this doesn't work. I'd like to see the full Traceback.

Comment: When adding self I get an error saying NameError: name 'player' is not defined.

Comment: Then player is not an instance of the class Player. You need to instantiate/initialize player before using it, then it will work. I'm not sure which class your draw() method is a member of, but within that class or method, you need to do the player initializing.

Comment: It should be `self.player.draw_shield_bar(self.screen, 50, 50)`, since the player is an attribute of the `Game` class (passing the shield is unnecessary). I only know that because I have access to the complete project. @MattMacy you really need to learn how to create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).